How to set a multiline value to a znode?
I have a znode as this:
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 13] get /myapp/columns
column1 String
column2 Int64

I'd like to change column2 to String however I don't know how to have multiline.
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 14] set /myapp/columns "column1 String\ncolumn2 String"
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 15] get /myapp/columns
column1 String\ncolumn2 String

That \n should be actual new line.
